# Delay a preloader fadeout with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, preloader

I see there are lots of questions on here about this but I can't seem to implement it properly into my site. I'm trying to get my preloader to run for the length of the gif (3 seconds) before fading out. My  code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        jQuery('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){jQuery(this).remove();});
    });
});
```

I see that I should probably use a setTimeout, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any tips?

I realize my code here performs the fadeout when the page loads rather than after time, but having trouble implementing the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `fadeOut()` uses the jQuery `fx` queue you can use `delay()` to achieve this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(window).on('load', () => {
    $('#preloader').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

Alternatively you can use `setTimeout()` as you mentioned in the question:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(window).on('load', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```